# Exactly similar PyCharm alternative

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I am currently using Pycharm. What I like about PyCharm are the following:

- Simplicity of creating virtualenvs
- Intellisense
- GUI package installer
- Console (automatically activates the venv)

However, I also lacked the following

- intellisense for javascript (I believe they require a paid
  license)

I recently tried visual studio but it lacked

- GUI package installer

Is there an ide that can give me all the aforementioned features? I need to use this ide for full stack development in Python

Comment: Did you try intelliJIDEA

Comment: A Python IDE isn't going to do JavaScript intellisense. A multi-language IDE could, but JetBrains uses a separate IDE for each language—which is part of the way they manage to make each one simple and powerful; they're as much like each other as possible, but no more so. I believe their JS offering is called WebStorm, but whatever it is, you should be able to find it on their website in seconds.

Comment: Pycharm is actually a plugin of intelliJIDEA. But honestly, although IDEA with python plugin has almost the same functions as Pycharm. It lacks convenient virtualenvs management.

Comment: BTW, even with a paid license, Pycharm doesn't support javascript.

Comment: @Sraw How about package installation if I could configure the virtual envs on my own?

Comment: It's a little difficult, it provides a GUI package installer for python, but you need to manually add repositories in "Manage Repositories".

Comment: @Sraw I see that I need the ultimate edition. [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206275629-javascript-autocompletion-in-html-files-and-in-xml-files)

Comment: Yes you need ultimate edition.

Comment: @Sraw How about Atom?